# await in es6 without needing response

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

I have a http call using axios, but I just wanted a call without needing its response.

```
try {
   axios.post('/somewhere', {id: 123}) //do I need to put `await` here?
} catch(err) {
   console.log(err)
}
```

Do I need the `await` keyword? I'm not assigning my response to any variable.

Comment: If nothing further in the code depends on the `.post`, then there's no need to `await` it

Comment: As post returns a promise, you can `.catch` instead of using `try`. Otherwise I don't think the promise rejection would get handled correctly.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think I have to do that coz I'm doing try catch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to `await` if you want the `try..catch` block to catch the errors from your `post`, or you do `axios.post('/somewhere', {id: 123}).catch(console.log);`

You also need to `await` if there is anything after the `axios.post()` that needs to wait untill the request has finished, wether you use the returned value or not; like maybe the function should not `return` before the request is finished.

Comment: I think this is the answer: `you need to await if you want the try..catch block`